# Update condition of for loop

Tags: vba, excel

Is it posible to update the for loop condition?
I need to loop from row 1 to lastrow of one sheet, when a condition is meet I need switch sheet and loop to end of that sheet.

Just for demo:

```
lr = 5
For i = 1 To lr
    If i = 3 Then
        lr = 500
        i = 50
    End If
Next i
```

This code ends at `i=51` because the for loop has not updated it's condition before it ends at the `Next i`.
Can this be solved some how?

Comment: use a [`while`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/while-end-while-statement) loop instead? the make your exit condition monitor a boolean flag variable and manually set that to false when you want to exit

Comment: Maybe... Can a while loop update itself? `EDIT: it can!`

Comment: It's not updating itself - the condition is based on a variable that get's checked each iteration. If your for loop did that it would lead to pretty confusing code I would think.

Comment: @Dan Why would it be confusing? If you need to update the loop conditions then you have no choice. I know I have used the same thing at some point in PHP too.

Comment: Right, PHP doesn't have any "annoying flaws" at all.

Comment: @Andreas it's unexpected behaviour for a for-loop, the whole point of them is to loop through a simple incremental iteration. If you aren't sure of the limit upfront then you just shouldn't be using a for-loop. Even the way it reads in English makes it sound like a predefined number of iterations. Deviating from norms in programming leads to confusion and errors (not to mention it will take the next person a lot of extra and unnecessary thinking to understand what you've done).

Comment: @Dan: Andreas and I are on the other side of the fence on this one as I suspect he has the same background as I. That said though, once you know this, you know it for ever.

Comment: @Bathsheba so long as no uses those `GoTo` solutions :) but many languages these days don't even have for-loops anymore (Python, Swift) but rather foreach or for in where you iterate over a collection that you definitely can't change. I just think it's a confusing idiom to state upfront what you are iterating over and then change that internally.

Comment: @Andreas Have a look at the language guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/looping-through-code under the *choosing a loop to use* section it states *For...Next: Using a counter to run statements a* ***specified number of times***

Comment: @Dan I see your point in that it may make the code hard to follow but that is what comments are for. I don't think the code will be any easier to understand with an while loop or any other loop. The "problem" remains. Each sheet has one week of data. I need to start at, for example Wednesday and loop one week forward. So I loop til last row or "Monday", whichever comes first then I go to the next sheet and find start point and last row and keep looping. And also as stated in comments below VBA has a fantastic debugging and steping through code that can make any code as clear as a diamond :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, VBA precomputes `lr` so subsequent changes to `lr` have no effect. If you come from a C, C++, or Java background (as do I) that can come as quite a shock! In terms of VBA's evolution from the various BASICs that have been around since the mid 1960s, the way it works makes perfect sense.

Your best bet is to refactor to a `Do` `While` or similar. In that case the stopping conditional is re-evaluated on each iteration.

Comment: *urghhhh* thanks.. Some things are really annoying with VBA.

Comment: You have to love the debug capabillities with steping through code. But yes it does have a few... flaws...

Comment: @Andreas: Absolutely! VBA is the only language in which I actively develop in a debugging session.

Comment: C, C++, Java, C# and others implement `for` loops with separate statements/instructions (notice these semicolons?) that specifically separate the initialization, exit condition, and increment parts. VB6/VBA `For` loop syntax *clearly* doesn't have that separation - that's just the way it is, no need to be condescending about it, and no need for that VBA-bashing talk either. Different languages have different mechanics, and they're clearly specified, and that's part of what makes different languages *different*.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: What does VB.NET do? I work in finance, where the average quant analyst codes in C, C++ and Java, and occasionally VBA. This corner of VBA trips such folk up all the time. Another one is the rounding when you "cast" a `double` to an `int`. Most languages truncate the decimal, VBA rounds it.

Comment: AFAICT, exactly the same behavior as VB6/VBA.

Comment: Exactly. AFAICT. So it's not known in a click of the finger. I don't know either but my bet is that it's evaluated on each iteration.

Comment: [Nope](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uz6dzE). That would have been a rather massively confusing change, given VB.NET was meant to appease the VB6 crowd migrating to .NET.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: That's good to know. I suspect it comes from the early BASICS (e.g. BBC model B, and the remarkably good BASIC that shipped with the Amstrad CPC series).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: VBA is a scaled-down version of God. When it came out in 1997 it was truly awesome. It's a pity though that Microsoft has invested minimal time and effort into it since then - barring a kludge to accommodate 64 bit Office products. PHP sucks since they reversed the associativity of the ternary conditional operator! Why?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Do While`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/using-doloop-statements) instead of `For`:

```
lr = 5
i = 1
Do While i < lr
    If i = 3 Then
        lr = 500
        i = 50
    End If
    i = i+1
Loop
```

Comment: `End While` , I think it should be `Wend` instead, am I wrong?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns that's correct. `While...Wend` is also an obsolete construct, deprecated by `Do While...Loop`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks, I've edited it.

Comment: But don't forget to change the preamble too.

Comment: This. This is the idiomatic code that answers OP's question without being condescending and without introducing silly work-arounds.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Do you have a link to the official documentation? I couldn't track it down through the forest of other VB docs online

Comment: @Dan the [language specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx), the [VB6 language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338033(v=vs.60).aspx), and here's the [Office VBA Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/office-vba-reference), where you'll find the [VBA For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/fornext-statement) documentation. I'll probably be contributing to these in the near future, it's all hosted on GitHub =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just for fun, you could cheat a little:

```
    lr = 5
begin:
    For i = 1 To lr
        If i = 3 And Not switched Then
            lr = 500
            switched = True
            GoTo begin
            i = 50
        End If
        Debug.Print i
    Next
```

Comment: I like this one, because it restarts from 1 the For Next. Nice one

Comment: Introducing a `GoTo` jump simply can't be the answer. If you wouldn't do it in Java or C#, then why would you even suggest doing it in VBA? Crap code is on the coder, not the language.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon. the question was _"Is it possible to update the for loop condition?"_. And my code answers that _very_ question. Furthermore I made a clear premise: "just for fun". Because the timing of my answer was such that other answers already pointed out the _right path_. I think what above can lead to consider removing your down vote

Comment: Fair enough. Had to edit to remove the vote though (rolled it back).

Answer (score 0):

You can be kind of tricky and code something for you to work. In this code, you will need a third variable to restart your For Loop (**please, note** this code won't do a real restart, when `i=3` it'll jump to 50, not restarting from 1. You will get 1, 2, 3, 50, 51, ....)

```
lr = 5
zz = 1

For_Loop_Start:

For i = zz To lr
    If i = 3 Then
        lr = 500
        zz = 50
        GoTo For_Loop_Start
    End If
Next i
```

Another option would be just a Do Until:

```
lr = 5
i = 1
Do Until i > lr
    If i = 3 Then
        lr = 500
        i = 49
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Of course, you can also use other options as Do While, Do While not,...etc.

Rules in programming are precomputed, but sometimes you can code stuff that "skip" those rules, and make the code what you want to. Is just imagination.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, it's kind of cheating LoL. Anyways, I'll take *warped* as a compliment :)

Comment: `You will get 1, 2, 3, 50, 51, ....)` is excactly what i need.

Comment: Glad to help! :)